# App Stuck on Splash screen only on simulator

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic-cordova

I am stuck on a white screen. This issues says to inspect I might be an JS error.

https://github.com/apache/cordova-ios/issues/938#issuecomment-656655260

Indeed I have one JS error which is not help full.

```
TypeError: 'application/octet-stream' is not a valid JavaScript MIME type.
```

I tried to build my APP on my ios device which works, only the simulator doesn't work.

Comment: Since the error is too vague, you might need to rollback the changes you did on your app before it was stuck in splash screen and retrace what's causing the issue.

Comment: The only change is the computer Intel to M1 ...

Comment: did you find any solution? @crg

Comment: Probably yes but I cannot tell you what was the problem. I changed my environment which I think was the problem